# Creating two different objects (from different models) at the same time - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

I have two models: `Product` and `Category`, which I want to tie together. 
Say each product has a unique category, how do I set Rails to create (or generate) a new `Category` object each time a user creates a new `Product` object?

Comment: you want to create completely new category with every new product??

Comment: what shall be the new category name??

Comment: No name. Just generate a new category with an ID integer.

Comment: Sounds like an after_create callback is required.

Comment: the purpose of a category is to group similar things under one name. If every product is its own category it defeats its purpose. Are you sure you want to do this ?

Comment: Yes.....since I'm using it for a slightly different purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
      after_create do
        Category.create product: self
      end
        has_one :category
    end

    class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :product
    end
```

and in console

```
 > a= Product.create
 > a.category
 => #<Category id: 1, product_id: 5, created_at: "2015-11-04 12:53:22", updated_at: "2015-11-04 12:53:22">
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if a category belongs so much to a product, why don't you add it to the product model? But still if you insist on the way you would like to have it coded, you can take advantage of callbacks like `after_create`, and write code for creating a category over there. This way, whenever a product is created, an associated category will be created along the way.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category
  after_create :create_category

  private
  def create_category
    # code for creating an associated category
  end 
end
```

Note: Most of the time, I need to save mobile number for a user in the database, and each user has a unique mobile number - so instead of defining a new model for mobile number, I tend to have it inside users table. But if the information for mobile number expands like its operator name, country code - I'd definitely split it into a separate table.